# Appium - get all items in UiScrollable (including not visible)

Tags: android, uiscrollview, appium

I need to verify text for **all** items in list (inside UiScrollable) using Appium.
Following approaches are not working for me:

1. `driver.findElements(MobileBy.id("com.author.app:id/title"))` - returns only currently visible elements (do not perform scroll till the end of list)
2. I know the way for verifying **one** item even when it's not visible (scroll is performed through the whole list)

```
    WebElement element =  driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable("
                    + "new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView("
                    + "new UiSelector().textContains(\"MyText\"));"))
```

But it's just for one predefined item.

3. I know there are some methods like `getChildByText/getChildByDescription` but they require some text (when I need to get all items).

So is there any way to get all list items (including scroll to items that are not currently visible)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it . It will scroll up or down depending on your elements visibility

```
    ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver().findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+element+"\").instance(0))"));

    ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver().findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + element + "\").instance(0))"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the same as I mentioned in #2 - scroll to specific element. But I need to get all elements in list (including elements that are not visible now and need to be scrolled to).

Comment: okay , in that case you need to just scroll down bit by bit and get all the element with using arraylist


int element_size = <Your elements size with identified >
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0 ;i <size;i++){

     <Logic for getting elements text>
     scrolldown();

}